# Omnicomplete and Vim, complete functions from non-imported classes

Tags: python, vim, numpy, omnicomplete

I am using Vim for editing python (using numpy, scipy) codes with the supertab plugin.

Is there a way to tell omnicomplete in `~/.vimrc` that `np` always denotes the numpy lib (as if I typed `import numpy as np` at the beginning of the code) and thus force it to complete e.g. `np.arr` to `np.array...`, even if the lib is not imported in that particular code?

The idea is that I write a script, in which I do `import numpy as np`, and this script calls for a lot functions, using `np` as well. However, they are placed in separate files, and thus by default, I cannot use the autocompletion when writing these functions, because Vim does not know, what `np` denotes.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You should look at a completion plugin with support for Python like [Jedi Vim](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim) or YouCompleteMe.

Comment: Vim's default Omnicompletion for python is very lacking. Given python is a dynamically typed language, you need a plugin like those mentioned above which can track your imports (amongst other things).

Comment: How did `np` get to the scope where it is used then? Using `from module import *` is one of the worst ideas as not only omnicompletion, but even the author cannot say for sure what is there in local scope. Doing `from module import np, …` is slightly better, but is not *explicit* `import numpy as np` more readable? Will you remember WTF is `np` if you revisit your module after a few months? Doing `:python import numpy as np` to import into vim global scope is one of the worst ideas as you are not the only user of this scope and the shorter the name the more likely somebody will take it.